# Guide to writing OpenGL and OpenGL ES compatible code?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, cross-platform, compatibility

I am familiar with the basic differences between OpenGL and OpenGL ES, e.g. no glBegin, glEnd, no quads and so forth.

My question is therefore not about the differences between the two APIs but about writing code that can actually work on both APIs and their various implementations, especially regarding ES, where implementations seem to vary more.

Naturally, that means conforming to features that are both present in the two APIs and identical syntax, nothing too fancy and cutting edge, with OpenGL ES 2 being the lowest common denominator.

Comment: You might find interesting reading [MaliOpenGLESEmulator](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0511c/BABBIBEA.html) docs. It's an OpenGL ES emulator(for MAC/PC) converting  calls from OpenGL ES to OpenGL. They list some details on difference between GL 2.0 and GLES 2.0. Like lack(obviously) of fixed-point data in GL, shader precision specifiers ant some other minor stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the new OpenGL ES compatibility extension [ARB_ES2_compatibility](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/ES2_compatibility.txt) (added to core in OpenGL 4.1)

Of course actually using the extension requires support for newer 4.1 desktop OpenGL but you can read through them and see what was required to get ES support on the desktop and avoid that in your ES code as much as possible. There may be some things that just aren't compatible with older desktop OpenGL versions though, mainly some shader stuff such as floating point precision.

There is also [ARB_ES3_compatibility](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/ES3_compatibility.txt) (core in OpenGL 4.3), but it's probably safe to ignore since it's for OpenGL ES 3.0).

Answer (score 2):

According to Khronos OpenGL ES is a subset of desktop OpenGL, so to write compatible code you just need to use OpenGL ES documentation.

A quote from http://www.khronos.org/opengles/

> OpenGL® ES is a royalty-free, cross-platform API for full-function 2D and 3D graphics on embedded systems - including consoles, phones, appliances and vehicles. It consists of well-defined subsets of desktop OpenGL

EDIT: As Justin Meiners pointed out in the comments there are actually some differences when it comes to the fine details. David C. Bishop's answer has more info on this.

Comment: This is not true. While the majority of code will transfer unchanged their are compatibility problems.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: I'm curious are those documented differences or bugs in implementation? I haven't found any of these compatibility problems and the khronos documentation still uses the word "subset". If it's not actually a strict subset I'd like to update my answer.

Comment: Some examples of differences would be shader precision qualifiers, differences in guaranteed sizes. If you look at the document ARB_ES2_compatibility in the other answer it describes all of the changes they have to make in order to be actually compatibility.